# Spring Boot and custom configuration of the application context

Tags: configuration, spring-boot-test, applicationcontext

I'm working with an ORM that I'm spinning up myself. Everything works fine in the application. Now, I need to be able to modify the configuration so that when the test cases run the tests talk to an in memory database.

I'm building with maven.

I have an application.yml file in src/main/resources which the application reads on startup.  I have a second file, application-derby.yml, file, which exists in src/test/resources. I've tried a variety of annotations to try and get this to work properly, but the src/main/resources/application.yml file seems to always get read and used to configure my beans.

```
@SpringBootTest
//@ActiveProfiles("derby")
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-derby.yml")
class StormApplicationTests {
```

I've tried both of those annotations, and neither seems to work.  The two yaml files are identical, except that in the one in test/resources the configuration is:

```
  dataSource:
    jdbcUrl: "jdbc:derby:memory:flashDB;create=true;user=flashmanager;password=password"
    driverClassName: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
    maximumPoolSize: 1
    username: flashmanager
    password: password
```

And in the src/java/resources the jdbc url value and the driver class are configured for a postgres database.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

After more playing around this set of annotations seems to solve my problem.

I use on the test case:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("derby")
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-derby.yml")
class StormApplicationTests {
```

The class contains this code:

```
    @Autowired
    private MyConfig config;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        Assert.isTrue(true, "default test");
    }
```

I put a break point on the Assert and examine the value of the config variable to see what value has been autowired. Previously, it was the postgres configuration, now it's the derby config.  Took a bit of work to figure out what was needed.